# How to create an IPA on XCode 4.3.2

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.3

Creating IPAs is no problem on 4.3.1 even though Apple changed the UI flow.
Just "Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Desployment"

[image: XCode 4.3.1]

XCode 4.3.2 does not have that option, only "Save Build Products" and "Export as XCode Archive"

Has anyone found out how to create an IPA?

Comment: My Xcode 4.3.2 looks exactly like the one in the screenshot.

Comment: Thats really strange.... could be a problem with my installation then ...

Comment: This was not related to XCode 4.3.2 and resolved by making sure that the current scheme did only archive one target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was not related to XCode 4.3.2 and resolved by making sure that the current scheme did only archive one target.

Comment: thanks for the update. might be useful to copy/paste this text into your answer as an "UPDATE" to help future users.

Answer (score 11):

just set your bundle identifier,
click Product –> Archive

follow the snaps
[image: 1st]

**select Distribute**

[image: 2nd]
[image: 3rd]
[image: 4th]

Comment: When doing this all I get is an ".xcarchive" that doesn't contain any *.ipa Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Before Xcode 4.3, when we wanna got a ipa file for our project, we do like this:
1. Product –> Archive
2. Organizer –> Archives –> select the archive
3. click the share button, then select the ipa option, and we done.

In the newest XCode 4.3 release, there were some changes.
1. before 4.3, there were three buttons, [validate, share, submit]
2. with 4,3 there are only two buttons, [validate, distribute]
3. here, when we want get a ipa file, we click the distribute button
4. select the [save for enterprise or Ad-Hoc deployment]
5. select the code signing identity.
6. save the ipa file , we done.

Comment: When doing this all I get is an ".xcarchive" that doesn't contain any *.ipa Am I missing something?